# PHP script which utilizes an SQL query returning false even though DB is updated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble with a simple PHP script that's part of my user registration system.

Upon entering user information in a registration form, I invoke the following PHP:

```
if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user != false) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["userID"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response); 
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
```

Now, here is the storeUser function which I'm accessing through an object reference to my DB_Functions class:

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $grade = "novice";
        $eloscore = 1200;
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Chessmates.User_Accounts (unique_id, name, email, Grade, encrypted_password, ELOscore, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$grade', '$encrypted_password', $eloscore, '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result != false) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that if my storeUser function returns false - which occurs in the case of mysql_query returning false - then what is returned to my Android application is an array containing the error_msg "Error occured in Registration".

This is exactly the message I am seeing when I initiate this whole registration cascade by clicking the 'register' button on my app.

HOWEVER, my database is being updated correctly!

I think I've narrowed the issue down to mysql_query returning false, but how could this be possible if the query is successful?

Comment: Can they enter their name as "201 or 1=1" and it saves to db?

Comment: You've left yourself open to SQL injection, consider switching to PDO and using PREPARED statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps your select query is actually the problem.

You are inserting into `Chessmates.User_Accounts`, yet you are selecting from `users`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue, just needed a second set of eyes to look at it. Thank you sir